# Turning on fans in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, dual-boot, temperature, fan

My fans don't turn on (ubuntu, on razer laptop). I downloaded lm-sensor in the hopes of manually setting a fan speed, but the fans shut off when I launched it, and I don't feel comfortable trying to find the on switch while watching the temperature keep rising. I can control them on windows with synapse, so I know the fans are user-accessible. Also didn't see an option to change it in the bios.

Does anyone know how to get to this setting quickly so that I can boot up and set fans to e.g. 50% before it gets hot?

Edit: I forgot to clarify that the fans have been working for a while, but the laptop tends to run hot on both os. Gets painfully hot even when just using chrome with unblocked vents in a cool room. I fixed the heat on windows by making the fans run thru razer synapse. I can still boot into ubuntu, but the temperatures quickly rise and I get force shut down, so I'm hoping I can figure out the config needed and be able to perform it quickly after boot.

Comment: Hi Kenneth, I don't know a whole lot about fan control, I know you'll need a driver, maybe https://openrazer.github.io/ has something? All computers fail-safe and hard-power off if the machine goes over temp, so you shouldn't have to manually monitor temp to prevent damage. Hardware should always self-regulate itself, and change the fan speed as necessary, if you are getting thermal throttling without the fans self-activating, its possible linux does have a driver and is controlling the fans but doing so incorrectly (wrong voltages or something). Be sure to post back if you find a solution :)

Comment: The fact that you are having problems on Windows and Linux sounds like your firmware isn't doing a good job regulating the fan speed. Have you checked if firmware updates are available? Maybe the hardware vendor has some advice?

Comment: @ThorSummoner thanks, I will dig around there for a driver. I messed around with lm-sensors a little more and it looks like ubuntu actually can't see the fans, only temperature sensors. Does that mean my hardware was managing it before I setup the software to do it and the software took control away?

Comment: @Martin It was a refurbished machine, and I'm still waiting on a response about audio drivers from the manufacturer that I eventually figured out, but there's a whole hassle about which device it actually is because their naming system is the year it comes out in but there are different downloads for the "mid-2019" vs "late-2019" devices

Answer (score 1):

Fixed! Just downloaded the [openrazer.github.io](http://openrazer.github.io) driver for the laptop and the fans started. I still don't have manual control, as it seems like lm-sensors/fancontrol still can't see the fans thru pwm, but these drivers are doing a better job of keeping it cool than whatever it was using before.